# Javascript event emitter | Dynamic event name

Tags: javascript, events, eventemitter

Is it possible to create a unique event for each payment address?

This is not working:

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter();

function emitpayment(address) {
    ee.emit("payment"+address,data);
}

function receivepayment(address) {
     ee.on("payment"+address, function (data) { 
           // whatever
     });
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried it? Event names are just strings.

Comment: yes i console.log something after ee.emit and it is not writing anything on the console. I also console.log something inside the ee.on function an it is not writing anything so the event is not being triggered

Comment: You have to register the event handler *before* you emit an event.

Comment: You also have to declare `data` in the example code above, as a parameter to "emitpayment". Your code above (with that fix) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Event names in Node (well, via the stock EventEmitter anyway) are simple strings.

You do need to make sure that the handler is registered *before* you start emitting events:

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter();

function emitpayment(address, data) {
    ee.emit("payment"+address,data);
}

function receivepayment(address) {
     ee.on("payment"+address, function (data) {
        console.log("received event payment" + address);
        console.dir(data);
     });
}

receivepayment("giant metallic balloon");
emitpayment("giant metallic balloon", { hello: "world" } );
```